# Need help in this code Disable printscreen in Angular 14

Tags: javascript, angular, angular14, printscreen, html5-clipboard-api

My exact requirement is I want to disable the printscreen option for the user.

I found one of the solution to disabling the printscreen.But some methods are

deprecated and looking for the working solution.

Here is the working solution Link:https://codepen.io/sartaj-husain/pen/NYRKGQ

I need help on the working solution of this code.

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have already attached the working link